# Assign a value from vector to variable with condition

Tags: r, vector

I try to assign a value from a vector(vector1) to a variable (var1) if the group value of the element in my data equals the number of observation in the vector (the vector consists of 2000 observations and I have exactly that amount of groups in my dataset). 
So I want to assign the first observation of the vector to all those observations that are in group 1, the second observation of the vector to all that are in group 2, etc. etc.

I can find a solution that works with loops, which is not very satisfying/efficient because my data is quite large.. my solution looks like follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(vector1)) {
  mydata$var1[mydata$group==i] <- vector1[i]
}
```

I tried to solve it with an additional vector that counts the observation and an if function.

```
vector2 <- seq(1, length(vector1), by = 1)
Mydata$var1 <- if (mydata$group==vector2) vector1
```

But of course the vector does not have the same amount of rows than the data has and it does not work. In the loop function I simply could use [i] in order to assign the value. How can I do this without the loop?

Comment: Can you give some dummy data such that we can play with it? And to be picky, the for-loop isn't efficient for small data sets, however, with small data sets we don't really care about the efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question completely. But if we assume that for each index there is a value in vector1, then this might work:

```
Mydata$var1 <- vector1[Mydata$group]
```